# React Jest Enzyme : Unable to pass router parameter

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a component named `AddEditVehicle` which renders when the route is `/vehicle/:vehicleId/edit`.

I need to test the React lifecycles of this component. So I have used Enzyme `mount` to render my component in the unit test in the following way.

```
beforeEach(async () => {
  wrapper = await mount(
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <AddEditVehicle match={{ params: { vehicleId } }} />
         </Provider>
       </BrowserRouter>
      );
     await wrapper.update();
});
```

this wrapper fails to pass the required params making following specs to fail.

```
it("expect `isEditMode` value to set", () => {
      const componentState = wrapper.find("AddEditVehicle").instance().state;
      expect(componentState.isEditMode).toEqual(true);
});
```

**Versions** :

- react ^16.4.2
- react-router ^4.3.1
- jest ^23.5.0
- enzyme ^3.4.4

Comment: You don't want to test with real router. Memory router is supposed to be used in unit tests.

Comment: I have tried with `<MemoryRouter initialEntries={["/vehicle/2/edit"]} initialIndex={0}>`, this is the console output when a print the match props in console `{ path: '/', url: '/', params: {}, isExact: false}`

Comment: @Satyaki you want to check state right ?

Comment: try to use `expect(wrapper.state().isEditMode).toBeTruthy()`

Comment: @Salahuddin No and Yes, actually, in my component, I'm calling an API on the basis of passed `id` at the URL. and setting the state variable to `edit mode` true. So, I need to have access on `id` as well as the state. In the present scenario, state does not reflect the correct edit state as it's unable to check the `id` of url

Answer (score 0):

The problem with my approach was my Component was part of a Route but still, I was wrapping the component with `withRouter` which is redundant. So, in the unit test when I was passing the Route `match` details it was getting overridded. Thus, removing the `withRouter` made the solution work.